# Точка доступа по wifi или bluetoch

Tags: wifi

На работе есть wifi. По работе используем планшеты подключенные к этому wifi. Этот планшет может раздать этот wifi. Если я сделаю планшет точкой доступа, и подключусь к ней через свой телефон, увидят ли айти что мой телефон подключен к wifi.? Я же получается не напрямую подключился к рутеру.. Просто есть еще одна точка доступа, от которой знаю пароль. Они блокируют все левые устройства через какое то время.

Comment: День добрый. Не нужно создавать однотипные вопросы. Лучше отредактируйте старый вопрос, если есть дополнения.